# Calculate Monday-Sunday week from a DateTime object

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm trying to write a method that will return a list of DateTimes representing a Monday-Sunday week. Its supposed to take the DateTime given to it and use it to calculate the surrounding dates

It calculates the starting date ok but the problem begins when it hits the last loop. With each run through the DateTime variable tmpDate should be incremented by 1 day, then added to the list. However, as it stands I'm getting back a List containing 7 starting dates.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong (I have the feeling I may be made to look like a bit of a simpleton  on this :) )?
Also, apologies if this is an often-asked question. Could see plenty of Start date/End Date and week number type questions, but none specifically dealing with this type of problem.

```
private List<DateTime> getWeek(DateTime enteredDate)
{ 
    /* Create List to hold the dates */
    List<DateTime> week = new List<DateTime>();
    int enteredDatePosition = (int)enteredDate.DayOfWeek;

    /* Determine first day of the week */
    int difference = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        difference++;
        if (i == enteredDatePosition)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    // 2 subtracted from difference so first and enteredDatePostion elements will not be counted. 
    difference -= 2;

    DateTime startDate = enteredDate.Subtract(new TimeSpan(difference, 0, 0, 0));
    week.Add(startDate);

    /* Loop through length of a week, incrementing date & adding to list with each iteration */
    DateTime tmpDate = startDate;

    for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++)
    {
        tmpDate.Add(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0));
        week.Add(tmpDate);
    }
    return week;
}
```

Comment: In case your code should work on different cultures, you can use `DateTime currentDay = new DateTime( enteredDate.Year, enteredDate.Month, enteredDate.Day );
while ( currentDay.DayOfWeek != DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.FirstDayOfWeek ) { currentDay = currentDay.AddDays( -1 ); }` to find the starting day of the week.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DateTime`s are immutable.
`tmpDate.Add(...)` returns a new DateTime, and does not modify `tmpDate`.

You should write `tmpDate = tmpDate.AddDays(1)` or `tmpDate += TimeSpan.FromDays(1)`

Comment: Cheers, That's worked a treat! I knew I'd come out of this one feeling silly :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this snippet is tailored towards Sunday trough Saturday, but you can try something like this:

```
DateTime ToDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays((6 - (int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek) - 7);
DateTime FromDate = ToDate.AddDays(-6);
```

Comment: Nice one! I'll give this a pop too.

Answer (score 1):

You're making your algorithm more complex than it needs to be. Check out this working snippet:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class MyClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // client code with semi-arbitrary DateTime suuplied
        List<DateTime> week = GetWeek(DateTime.Today.AddDays(-2));
        foreach (DateTime dt in week) Console.WriteLine(dt);
    }

    public static List<DateTime> GetWeek(DateTime initDt)
    {
        // walk back from supplied date until we get Monday and make 
        // that the initial day
        while (initDt.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday) 
            initDt = initDt.AddDays(-1.0);

        List<DateTime> week = new List<DateTime>();

        // now enter the initial day into the collection and increment
        // and repeat seven total times to get the full week
        for (int i=0; i<7; i++)
        { 
            week.Add(initDt);
            initDt = initDt.AddDays(1.0);
        }

        return week;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers! This is just the ticket too. Never even considered sticking minus numbers into AddDays

Comment: As in refactor the original code I posted? Would that not make the question less useful for someone looking at it in future; if they can't see what the problem was in the first place? Sorry if its a silly question, pretty new here.